# environment within environment within command

Tags: macros, environments, enumerate

So.... I'm trying to create (what I assume) is to be a simple command that tries to do some nice formatting. Here is what I have.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{question}{\bf}{\normalfont}
\newenvironment{answer}{\it}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\qna}[2]{
    \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{
        \begin{question}
            #1
        \end{question}
        \begin{answer}
            #2
        \end{answer}
    }
}
```

Now, this seems to work perfectly when I input any string.

```
\qna{Here's a q}{Here's an answer}
```

BUT I'm getting into issues when I try and pass in a non string as my second variable. Example

```
\qna{Here's a q}{Here an answer in list format
\begin{enumerate}
    \item answer 1
    \item answer 2
\end{enumerate}
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong and what a potential way of fixing it would be.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{question}{\bf}{\normalfont}
\newenvironment{answer}{\it}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\qna}[2]{
    \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{
        \begin{question}
            #1
        \end{question}
        \begin{answer}
        #2
        \end{answer}
    }
}


\begin{document}
    \qna{test}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: (1) you should not be using `\it` and `\bf`, those are not LaTeX, (2) your problem might be that the colorbox need what ever it is surrounding to be a box, at least when you are adding lists. Try addin a `minipage`. BTW: Are you sure you want to use a syntax like this, it seems rather cumbersome. Have a look at the `environ` package, that might be useful.

Comment: please always post complete test documents not fragments so this is not tested but `\fcolorbox` like `\mbox` is a hmode (LR mode) construct that does not allow display constructs like lists, you probably want `\fcolorbox{black}{yelow}{\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}\begin{question}..`  Also ypu are missing `%` from teh ends of most of your lines in the definition which will produce bad spaces in the output

Comment: Sorry for posting fragments everyone. I've created a MWE and posted at the bottom.

Comment: You know that there are packages like `exsheets` and classes like `exam` for this, right? No real need to invent the wheel once more.

Comment: Looks like the minipage is the solution to go with. Although cumbersome, it does do what I need fairly simply. I specifically didn't add % as I wanted the specific spaces added by leaving them out. Also, @Johannes_B No, I didn't, but after looking at those packages it won't do what I want. Just because my example shows a QnA system doesn't mean I'm actually creating a QnA system. It's just an example which is easily relatable =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `\fcolorbox` is that does not allow `lists` inside it. A `minipage` or `parbox` would help in this case, but both are not breakable. I used the `tcolorbox` package and the `tcolorbox` environment to provide for a breakable box (amongst many,many other configurable options, e.g. box corners, color, title line etc.)

In addition, a package like `exam` or `exsheets` are designed for such tasks.

I used `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand` for 'easier' *long arguments* to the command instead of `\newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}%
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{question}{\bfseries}{\normalfont}%
\newenvironment{answer}{\itshape}{\normalfont}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\qna}{+m+m}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=yellow]
        \begin{question}
          #1
        \end{question}
        \begin{answer}
            #2
        \end{answer}
      \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}


\qna{Here's a q}{Here an answer in list format
\begin{enumerate}
    \item answer 1
    \item answer 2
\end{enumerate}
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I can't use the above method due to internal reasons, it's a phenomenal answer for most use cases. Thanks =)

Comment: @AramPapazian: Thanks for accepting the answer, but **why** can't you use this (or a similar approach)?

Comment: I'd need to install tcolorbox (the files aren't already included on my machine unfortunately) and so I wouldn't be able to use that package. (And yes, I could download the files and import them, but I am not allowed to on the machine I am using unfortunately)

Comment: @AramPapazian: It's always possible to install a package in a local directory of your user folder.

Comment: yes, I know that. I mean I'm literally not allowed to download anything onto the computer I am currently using... As in, I'd get in trouble if I did... As in, I'd rather not get fired (no matter how trivial) ... and yes I realise how dumb this policy is, but I'm not the one who made it =/

Comment: @AramPapazian: Get your own machine ;-)